# css em contact form 7

Tags: css, wordpress

Estou usando o contact form 7 em (https://petspa.vet.br/contato/) e o retorno da submissão está com a fonte em branco:

```css
.wpcf7 .wpcf7-response-output {
  margin: 30px 0 0;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  border: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

[image: mensagem de retorno com a fonte branca]

Já alterei a cor no style.css do tema e ela ainda retorna para o #ffffff

```css
.wpcf7 .wpcf7-response-output {
  margin: 30px 0 0;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  border: 0;
  color: #19191a;
}
```

Comment: Para mim está exibindo preto a fonte, qual o problema?

Comment: Primero tente limpar o cache do seu browser, depois coloca !important no color para ver se aplica a cor

Comment: Muito obrigada, pessoal! Realmente era só cache mesmo.